# Should i use WebSockets over REST?

Tags: rest, api, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a project that requires realtime data transfer between client and server. It is a location-based app that needs continuous location data of around 50-70 clients at a time.

Comment: `SwaggerSocket` (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-socket) is an application level protocol for REST over Websocket, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373734/is-rest-over-websockets-possible

Comment: @ralfhtp I am using flask at backend and I found this cool library socket.io will it do the job.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339393/how-can-socket-io-and-restful-work-together/21813645 yes

Comment: thanks mate @ralfhtp